print organization name with at least three subset (have at least three organization in subset)
I write a query to solve this problem,
Print Organization name that have at least three organization subset.


SELECT DISTINCT  ?Name
WHERE {
    ?organization a foaf:Organization .
    ?organization foaf:name ?organizationName .
    ?organization rdf:subClassOf ?y .
    ?y foaf:name ?Name .
    FILTER(?y > 3 )
}



But I think the result is not correct, where is my problem here?

not that we know the data model and w.r.t. the SPARQL query it's somewhat difficult to derive, but you have to group by the name and count things.  Put something like that instead of the filter expressions and the end of the query: SELECT ... WHERE { ... } GROUP BY ?Name HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT ?y) >=3)

Presumably you mean rdfs:subClassOf . If organisations are modelled this way in your dataset then this should work:
SELECT DISTINCT  ?Name
WHERE {
    ?organization a foaf:Organization .
    ?organization rdfs:subClassOf/rdfs:subClassOf/rdfs:subClassOf* ?y .
    ?y foaf:name ?Name .
}

